# How to use two versions of AFNetworking in same project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

I have to use version 1.x and 3.0 of AFNetworking in same project. i went through with the questions on SO.

[Using two versions of afnetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698872/using-2-versions-of-afnetworking-in-same-ios-project)

[Two Versions in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663673/use-two-versions-of-the-same-library)

But the problem is I don't understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible: if you want to include multiple version of the same framework in the same project you end to cause duplicate symbol errors.
To make an example of AFN, RestKit depends on AFN 1.x while another library you want to use requires 3.x. You won't be able to use both of them in the same class.

To more information take a look to the 3.x [requirements](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/README.md#requirements).

And you could look [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide) to know (AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide) the differences between versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rename one version of them. Rename AFNetwork to BFNetwork or do something like that.